# How does retry_exponential_backoff work in Airflow tasks?

Tags: airflow

How do the parameters `retries`, `retry_delay` and `retry_exponential_backoff` interact? When there is a retry, when is it scheduled? [Exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) sounds interesting, but how does it work?

e.g. what happens with these parameters? When are the retries scheduled?

```
retries=3,
retry_delay=300,
retry_exponential_backoff=True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for understanding how Airflow implements exponential backoff can be found in `airflow/models/taskinstance.py` ([link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/119cd677ec0852aede049243f5347bc46833889d/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1940)). Exponential backoff will double the wait time between retries after every retry.

Here are some examples of different wait intervals between retries to illustrate how long the scheduler will wait to re-schedule a task for a retry:

| retries | retry_delay | retry_exponential_backoff | number of seconds to first retry | NoSt second retry | NoSt to third retry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 60 | True | 60 | 120 | 240 |
| 3 | 60 | False | 60 | 60 | 60 |
| 1 | 120 | True | 120 | N/A | N/A |
| 1 | 120 | False | 120 | N/A | N/A |
| 3 | 300 | True | 300 | 600 | 1200 |
| 3 | 300 | False | 300 | 300 | 300 |